# Import googlemaps via importmaps in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

What is the way to go to load GoogleMaps via importmaps in Rails7?

I've seen folks import it via the script-tag like this:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= Rails.application.credentials[:p10_google_maps_js_api_key] %>&callback=initMap" async defer data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>`

but I would like to take advantage of the new importmap feature of Rails 7. Unfortunately I don't understand how i could trigger the `initMap` callback without using it as a script.

Answer (score 2):

In 2023, Google soft-deprecated their "legacy script loading tag" (the one with the callback), and thanks to their new loader package there is a much better way to do this now. No need to dispatch a window event.

Pin their new npm [`@googlemaps/js-api-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) package:

```
./bin/importmap pin @googlemaps/js-api-loader
```

and use it in your controller like this:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["mapDiv"]

  connect() {
    const loader = new Loader({
      apiKey: "~~~",
      version: "quarterly",
      libraries: ["maps", "geocoding", "marker", "elevation"]
    })

    const mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -7, lng: -47 },
      zoom: 1,
    }

    loader
      .load()
      .then((google) => {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapDivTarget, mapOptions)
        this.elevation = new google.maps.ElevationService()
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("error loading gmaps")
      })
      //  Or, instead of `load()` above, await a library import:
      //  .importLibrary('maps')
      //  .then(({ Map }) => {
      //    new Map(this.mapDivTarget, mapOptions);
      //  })

  }
}
```

Took me days to realize I could use with `importmap-rails`. I didn't find any other answer on SO explaining it.

Comment: awesome! thanks for pointing that out. i will look into it :)

Answer (score 1):

So there is a Stimulus component that you could use [stimulus-places-autocomplete](https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-places-autocomplete/). However, you could easily implement this yourself and save you the trouble of pulling in a dependency.

At the end of the day, the google callback needs to be fired off. The way most have gotten around this is by creating an event and attaching that to the window. You then add a `data-action` to your views controller `div` that will look for this even and fire a callback of its own. That callback being an initializer within your Stimulus controller itself.

##########places_controller.rb##########

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["street", "city", "state", "zip"];

  connect() {
    // Can also initialize this with a CustomEvent
    const event = new Event('google-maps-callback', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    })
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  // additional actions
}
```

##########index.html.erb##########

```
<div
  data-controller="places"
  data-action="google-maps-callback@window->places#initMap"
>
  <%# view code here %>
</div>
```

This still is not a solution that I love. However, its the workaround that we have for now.

Comment: thanks a lot! let me try this out in the next few days and text you back as soon as i've played around with it a little ...